# populating the uploaded file name and size in a html table, appending new values when user choose files at second time

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

Question is i have table in which i want to populate the values of file name and file size after user click the choose file button and select any number of files, Now the issue is if the user click choose files button second time i want to append the new values in the table and add the new file in the array so that it can uploaded.. my code is,

**html form code:**

```
<form id="simpleuploadform" method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="span10" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <legend>Simple Upload</legend>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="getFileSizeandName(this);"/>
            <div id="successdiv" hidden="true" class="label label-success">Image uploaded successfully</div>
            <div id="errordiv" hidden="true" class="label label-error">Image not successfully uploaded</div>
            <div id="streamdiv" hidden="true" class="label label-warning">Issue while uploading try again</div>
        </td>
        <td id="renameFile" align="right"></td>
        <td id="removeFile" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="uploaddiv">
                <table id="uploadTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="200" height="200" scrolling="yes">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbodyid">
                        <tr id="tr0">
                            <td id="filetd0" height="10px" width="50px"></td>
                            <td id="filesizetd0" height="10px" width="5px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="tr1">
                            <td id="filetd1" height="10px" width="50px"></td>
                            <td id="filesizetd1" height="10px" width="5px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="tr2">
                            <td id="filetd2" height="10px" width="50px"></td>
                            <td id="filesizetd2" height="10px" width="5px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="tr3">
                            <td id="filetd3" height="10px" width="50px"></td>
                            <td id="filesizetd3" height="10px" width="5px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="tr4">
                            <td id="filetd4" height="10px" width="50px"></td>
                            <td id="filesizetd4" height="10px" width="5px"></td>
                        </tr>                                           
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="filecount" height="10px" width="50px"></td>
                            <td id="totalsize" height="10px" width="5px"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="CloseAndRefresh();" value="Start Upload" id="startButton" disabled>
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="Clear();" value="Clear" id="clearButton" disabled>
            <input type="button" class="btn" onClick="window.close();" value="Close">
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var totalsizeOfUploadFiles = 0;
function getFileSizeandName(input)
{
    var select = $('#uploadTable tbody');
    $('#renameFile').empty();$('#removeFile').empty();

    if(input.files.length > 0)
    {
        $('#renameFile').append($('<a id="renameRec">Rename Selected</a>'));
        $('#removeFile').append($('<a id="removeRec">Remove Selected</a>'));
        $('#startButton').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#clearButton').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    //if(input.files.length <= 5)
    //{
        for(var i =0; i<input.files.length; i++)
        {           
            var filesizeInBytes = input.files[i].size;
            var filesizeInMB = (filesizeInBytes / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);
            var filename = input.files[i].name;
            //alert("File name is : "+filename+" || size : "+filesizeInMB+" MB || size : "+filesizeInBytes+" Bytes");

            if(i<=4)
            {               
                $('#filetd'+i+'').text(filename);
                $('#filesizetd'+i+'').text(filesizeInMB);
            }
            else if(i>4)
                select.append($('<tr id=tr'+i+'><td id=filetd'+i+'>'+filename+'</td><td id=filesizetd'+i+'>'+filesizeInMB+'</td></tr>'));

            totalsizeOfUploadFiles += parseFloat(filesizeInMB);
            $('#totalsize').text(totalsizeOfUploadFiles.toFixed(2)+" MB");
            if(i==0)
                $('#filecount').text("1file");
            else
            {
                var no = parseInt(i) + 1;
                $('#filecount').text(no+"files");
            }                       
        }
    //}
}

function CloseAndRefresh() 
{
    var daa = '<%=status%>';
    if(daa == "true")
        $('#successdiv').show();
    else if(daa == "false")
        $('#errordiv').show();
    else
        $('#streamdiv').show();
    opener.location.reload(true);
    self.close();       
}

function Clear()
{
    $('#uploadTable tbody tr td').each(function(){
        $(this).text("");
    });
    $('#uploadTable tfoot tr td').each(function(){
        $(this).text("");
    });
}
```

i am trying to do as like this http://www.shutterfly.com/ image upload.

any help will be appreciated, thank you friends...

Comment: Don't duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775443/populating-the-uploaded-file-name-and-size-in-a-html-table-appending-new-values

Comment: sorry its a duplicate question means, kindly suggest me the answer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating away using javascript, function `CloseAndRefresh` on clicking submit button.

What actually happens is that the uploading request is being submitted while the `CloseAndRefresh` function is being executed at almost the same time using different thread. If the upload request is not fast enough, the web page will get refresh first and your upload request get terminated immediately. There is no easy way to prevent this using your existing code.

You should use advanced method of uploading like jQuery uploading plugin to send the request. The plugin provide an binder to execute function on successful/failed submittsion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I use CloseAndRefresh function for closing the popup window and refresh the home page, so that the uploaded will reflects in the home page.                                                               You are correct when i try to do two task at same time it arise issues. Let me clear my situation, i want to upload a set of files, for each time file is choosen by user must be reflects in the file list and click start upload button i want to upload and throws the appropriate msg's to the client side.

Comment: that's why i said you should use jquery uploading plugin or other advanced method like ajax without refreshing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you gigadot, i solve the issue as like below,

The html form have the same code as i posted earlier, in the previous js code i have the `CloseAndRefresh()` method i remove it now from js as well as from the submit button onclick event.

When the form action called the controller, in which i have the code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String UploadReceipts(@RequestParam("files[]") List<MultipartFile> file, Model model) throws IOException {
            boolean status = false;
    try
    {
        for(int i=0; i< file.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!file.get(i).isEmpty())
            {
                CommonsMultipartFile cm = (CommonsMultipartFile) file.get(i);
                status = simpleUploadService.uploadFileandSave(cm);
                model.addAttribute("status", status);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        status = false;
        model.addAttribute("status", status);
    }
    return "pages/simpleUploadStatus";
}
```

Now i redirect it to another page in which i throws the appropriate messages for the user.
that's all...